# On "using" to abbreviate object definitions of generic type

Tags: c#, using-directives

I'm quite new to C# so I apologize if this has been asked before but I've done some searches and haven't found what I'm looking for.

Specifically, I'm aware I can use the keyword `using` in the following manner to (in some way) mimic the use of `typedef`:

```
using myStringDict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>;
```

or other pre-defined types.

I am curious to know if there is a way to do this with generic types. As in

```
using mySomethingDict<T,K> = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<T,K>; //this doesn't work
```

This is all to avoid having to include `using System.Collections.Generic;` in my files (as there are many files in my project).

Alternative advice is also welcome.

Comment: "as there are many of them" Many usings? Why do you care? You write them once and shouldn´t bother for them at all. Actually the `using` is just to avoid ambioguities, when two classes from different namespaces have the same name but you use them both in your class. Don´t use this keyword as equivalent for `typedef` as it simply *is not*.

Comment: Your post is muddled *many of them*  many what - files or using statements?  If you add  `using  System.Collections.Generic` you can just reference `Dictionary<K, V>`

Comment: The reason, I was looking to avoid "importing" an entire namespace every time I need an Object (or something else), is because I recall reading it's a bad habit to do this in large projects. Though, I appreciate both your answers.

Comment: Maybe you should add where you read this. As you may see in my answer, this inly refers to languages like JAVA. In C# you can´t import a complete namespace.

Comment: It's entirely possible I'm mis-remembering as I've been doing a lot of reading on several languages recently. Probably getting things jumbled up in my head. It's good to know C# won't import the entire namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You´re misusing the [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)-statement. The meaning of this statement depends on its context. In your case you refer to the "using alias directive" to define an alias for a namespace or a type. However this is usually used to avoid ambuigities, e.g. when you have your own class `Math` defined but want to use the `System.Math`-class in your code also. So in order to be able to refer to both types, you can use a `using` as alias, e.g. `using MyMath = MyNamespace.Math`.

So `using` is *not* the C#-equivalent for a `typedef`.

On the other side it´s absolutely okay to have multiple usings in your code, it simply shows the classes that are used by your code. You shouldn´t bother for that at all. In contrast to your statement in your question you´re *not* importing a complete namespace. You simply load the classes you want to use in your code. You could do the exact same by don´t use any `using` and allways use fully-qualified names for all the types, e.g. `System.Generics.Dictionary`. This will compile to the exact same code, but is harder to read and write.

This difers from how JAVA imports types - which might be the cause for your confusion. In JAVA you can write `import MyNameSpace.*` to load *all* classes within the namespace `MyNameSpace`. In C# however there´s no such thing, you´re just refering to *single types*.

[See also the examples on the alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/how-to-use-the-global-namespace-alias)

Answer (score 3):

No you can't do this, using aliases cannot contain type parameters. From the specification:

**9.4.1 Using alias directives**

> Using aliases can name a closed constructed type, but cannot name an
>   unbound generic type declaration without supplying type arguments. For
>   example:

```
namespace N1
{
    class A<T>
    {
        class B {}
    }
}
namespace N2
{
    using W = N1.A;         // Error, cannot name unbound generic type
    using X = N1.A.B;           // Error, cannot name unbound generic type
    using Y = N1.A<int>;        // Ok, can name closed constructed type
    using Z<T> = N1.A<T>;   // Error, using alias cannot have type parameters
}
```